# Cannot undistort points using OpenCv undistortPoints method

Tags: python, c, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm trying to undistort certain points of an image using the "undistort points" method of OpenCV, but without success.
[image: Here an example where I undistort all the whole picture]

These will be my undistorsion coefficients

```
  optic_camera_matrix: [[710.52285,  0.0,      882.14702],
                        [0.0,        713.9636, 638.8421],
                        [0.0,        0.0,      1.0]],

  distorsion_coeffs: [[-0.4176419401669212,
                                 0.15978235598732332,
                                 -8.299875092923166e-05,
                                 -0.001784191694247801,
                                 -0.027396621999692457]],
```

Even though I am capable of undistorting the whole image, in order to optimize the camera processing time, if I undistort just the corner points (red points of the image):

```
distorted_border_points = np.array([[[584,1415],
                                        [576,457],
                                        [1956,415],
                                        [1996,1422],
                                        [1261,242],
                                        [1281,1594]]],np.float32)

undistorted_points =  cv2.undistortPoints(distorted_border_points, optic_camera_matrix, distorsion_coeffs)
```

I get this in return:

```
[[[ -6.40190065e-01   1.66883194e+00]
  [ -4.87006754e-01  -2.88225353e-01]
  [ -1.82562262e-01   3.74070629e-02]
  [ -5.28450182e-04  -3.51850584e-04]
  [  8.09574544e-01  -8.40054870e-01]
  [ -5.28259724e-02  -1.22379906e-01]]]
```

If plotted, they don't align in a rectangle, like in the first image.

I believe the undistorsion coefficients are well calcualted (since undistorsion works on the first image), but here I attach the code of the cam

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import json
import numpy as np

directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)


def get_optic_calibration_parameters(device,config_folder=None):
    if config_folder is None:
        optic_calibration_path = directory + '/../config/' + \
            device + '/optic_calibration.json'
    else:
        optic_calibration_path = config_folder + device + '/optic_calibration.json'

    if not os.path.exists(optic_calibration_path):
        os.makedirs(optic_calibration_path[:-22])

    with open(optic_calibration_path) as optic_calibration_file:
        optic_calibration = json.load(optic_calibration_file)

    optic_camera_matrix = optic_calibration['optic_camera_matrix']
    distorsion_coeffs = optic_calibration['distorsion_coeffs']
    optic_resolution = optic_calibration['optic_resolution']

    return optic_camera_matrix, distorsion_coeffs, optic_resolution


def _save_calibration_parameters(camera_matrix, distorsion_coeffs, optic_resolution, device, config_folder=None):

    if config_folder is None:
        optic_calibration_path = directory + '/../config/' + \
            device + '/optic_calibration.json'
    else:
        optic_calibration_path = config_folder + device + '/optic_calibration.json'

    if not os.path.exists(optic_calibration_path):
        os.makedirs(optic_calibration_path[:-22])

    optic_calibration_parameters = {'optic_camera_matrix': camera_matrix.tolist(),
                                    'distorsion_coeffs': distorsion_coeffs.tolist(),
                                    'optic_resolution': optic_resolution}

    with open(optic_calibration_path, 'wb') as optic_calibration_file:
        json.dump(optic_calibration_parameters, optic_calibration_file)

    return


def _get_image_points(plot=False, dim=(4, 5), input_dir='calibration_samples',extension='jp'):
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    # prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
    objp = np.zeros((dim[0] * dim[1], 3), np.float32)
    objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:dim[1], 0:dim[0]].T.reshape(-1, 2)

    # Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
    objpoints = []  # 3d point in real world space
    imgpoints = []  # 2d points in image plane.

    images = glob.glob(input_dir + '*.'+extension+'*')
    for fname in images:
        img = cv2.imread(fname)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Find the chess board corners
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (dim[1], dim[0]), None)

        # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
        if ret == True:
            objpoints.append(objp)

            corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(
                gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
            imgpoints.append(corners2)

            # Draw and display the corners
            if plot:
                img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(
                    img, (dim[1], dim[0]), corners2, ret)
                cv2.imshow('img', img)
                cv2.waitKey(500)

    resolution = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])

    return imgpoints, objpoints, resolution


def calibrate_camera(optic_resolution, imgpoints, objpoints, device, config_folder=None):

    _, camera_matrix, distorsion_coeffs, _, _ = cv2.calibrateCamera(
        objpoints, imgpoints, optic_resolution, None, None)

    _save_calibration_parameters(
        camera_matrix, distorsion_coeffs, optic_resolution, device, config_folder=config_folder)

    return
```

To execute the function I loaded different images:

```
imgpoints, objpoints, optic_resolution = _get_image_points(plot=False, dim=(4,5), input_dir=calibration_samples)
_show_N_chessborders(N=3, dim=(4,5), input_dir=calibration_samples)
calibrate_camera(optic_resolution, imgpoints, objpoints,device, config_folder=config_folder)
```

And that's how I store the json config files

I would appreciate it if anyoce could help me with a solution. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly can be seen in the picture with just the colored dots? Why are there somewhere else than in the picture above?

Comment: The picture I show is the result of my code. If I use the undistorsion function to the points I drawed in the first image this is the output I get. I was expecting anyone could help me make it work.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, the `getOptimalNewCameraMatrix` function is only for when you don't want to the black sides while undistorting an entire image (see [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/101398/what-does-the-getoptimalnewcameramatrix-function-does/) question), and not for when you are undistorting individual points. Also, it seems `P` and `R` in `undistortPoints` are only for stereo vision things.

I would simplify it, and just say:

```
undistorted_points =  cv2.undistortPoints(np.array(points), optical_camera_matrix, d)
```

where `optical_camera_matrix` is the matrix directly from the `calibrateCamera` function. Just make sure that `points` are a [`1xN or Nx1 2-channel`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints) array.

**UPDATE:**

I realized what the problem was. The secret is the sentence on this [website](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints).

> Also the function performs a reverse transformation to projectPoints()

As I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong) the undistorted points are normalized. In order to put them back in pixel units simply do the following (in pseudo code):

```
for each point in undistorted_points:
    point = point * focal_length + boresight
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Hein Wessels. Thank you for your answer. It didn't work either. I updated the post so you can see the output of using the opencv undistortPoints function.Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you show your code from the `calibrateCamera` to `undistortPoints`?

Comment: you mean "how do I obtain optic_camera_matrix and distorsion_coeffs"? This code must be right because these 2 parameters work properly when undistorting the full image (see the first img).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but something somewhere is going wrong. A few weeks back used the `undistortPoints` function just as you, and it worked fine. So the next step is to read your code.

Comment: I updated the post as you requested! Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you're still struggling with this (probably not XD), I updated my answer. Sorry for the long delay.

Answer (score 1):

For the output space is normalized case, you can set the P=optic_camera_matrix. It is written in the document that "If matrix P is identity or omitted, dst will contain normalized point coordinates":
http://amroamroamro.github.io/mexopencv/matlab/cv.undistortPoints.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess ,you want to get the points from undistort image .Below is the output

```
 [[ 654.7192   463.65854]]

 [[2376.9995   393.60895]]

 [[2042.0536  1311.5094 ]]

 [[1346.7653   261.61887]]

 [[1510.6827  1794.8864 ]]]
```

code:

```
self.newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix (optic_camera_matrix, distorsion_coeffs, (self.w,self.h), 1, (self.w,self.h)) # w,h is the image shape 
distorted_border_points = np.array([[[584,1415],
                                        [576,457],
                                        [1956,415],
                                        [1996,1422],
                                        [1261,242],
                                        [1281,1594]]],np.float32)
        
new = cv2.undistortPoints(distorted_border_points,optic_camera_matrix,distorsion_coeffs,None,self.newcameramtx)
print(new)
```